# How do I keep just the first letters (abbreviations) of words AND all the numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings like "33 minutes" and "2 hours 20 minutes" for example and I want them abbreviated to "33m" and "2h20m."

So far I have this (based on a similar question on stack exchange): https://jsfiddle.net/3tzrs7we/

```js
var str1 = "33 minutes";
var str2 = "2 hours 20 minutes";

var str3 = str1.replace(/(\w)\w*\W*/g, function(_, i) {
  return i.toUpperCase();
})
var str4 = str2.replace(/(\w)\w*\W*/g, function(_, i) {
  return i.toUpperCase();
})
alert(str3 + ", " + str4);
```

But that returns "3M" and "2H2M."

(That's just an example, in my code it looks like `${r.time.replace(/(\w)\w*\W*/g, function (_, i) {return i.toUpperCase();})}`)

Comment: If you don't want to convert to upper case just drop the `.toUpperCase()` part: https://jsfiddle.net/3tzrs7we/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```js
var str2 = "  2 hours 20 minutes  ";
document.write(str2.replace(/([a-z])\w+|\s+/g, "$1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a regular expression for this limited case:

```
var long = "2 hours 20 minutes";
var short = long.replace(" minutes", "m").replace(" hours", "h");
```

Comment: This works, but I also have strings with "minute," "hour," "days," "day," etc. so it gets a little unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1 = "33 minutes";
var str2 = "2 hours 20 minutes";

var str3 = str1.replace(/(\w)\w*\W*/g, function(_, i) {
return i.toLowerCase();
})
var str4 = str2.replace(/(\w)\w*\W*/g, function(_, i) {
return i.toLowerCase();
})
alert(str3 + ", " + str4);
```